# Why kid's electric car chargers usually have 12V 1A output?

Tags: battery-charging

We have got a kid's electric car, without charger and we've told that we have to replace the batteries. It has two serial connected 6V 7AH 20HR batteries. I want to replace with a single 12V 7AH 20HR (hope this is OK). Chargers for these toys usually have a 12V 1A output. I looked for a better, automatic charger, like the CTEK MXS 3.8. But this has 14.4V output. Is there any reason to charge a battery like below with 12V 1A?

Battery properties:
Cycle use: 14.4-15V
Standby use: 13.6-13.8V
Initial current: less than 2.1A

Comment: The manufacturer has deemed it safe and good way to charge the toys. Or at least the cheapest they can without batteries burning up too often. It might read 12V 1A if it is a charger meant for 12V batteries, it might not output 12V but something else.

Comment: If a charger is intended to charge 12 volt lead-acid batteries, it will output up to 14.4 volts.  If you limit the charging voltage to 12 volts, the battery won't get anywhere near a full charge.